# Responsive triangle?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, css-shapes

I have something like this in my Bootstrap HTML (probably, it is just a down-pointing low triangle):

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <div class="triangle"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS works like this:

```
.triangle {
  margin-top:-1px;
  height: 60px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 80px 778px 0 778px;
  border-color: #332638 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

But this is not responsive. I mean on mobile screens this triangle still keeps the same size (since it is in pixels, obvioulsy) and keeps a horizontal scrolling.

The question is: is it possible to make it responsive? I know the answer is somewhere close, but I'm still not an expert, just trying to figure it out.

Thank you! :)

This is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ebwc7c3m/), by the way.

Comment: If you change these values to, say, use the `viewport width` uniut instead of pixels (`vw`), that should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple replace the `px` unit with a responsive unit that is based on the viewport. For example, you could use the `vw` (viewport width) unit, which represents the width of the viewport divided by 100. Do not use `%` as they use different values for vertical and horizontal axis', but if you use `vw` or `vh` (or even `vmin` or `vmax`) you get a responsive triangle. See the snippet below, although I have modified the values a bit so they display better, and you can resize the screen and notice one of them is actually resizing!

```css
.triangle {
  margin-top:-1px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 8px 77px 0 77px;
  border-color: #332638 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.triangle-responsive {
  margin-top:-1px;
  width: .6vw;
  height: .6vw;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: .8vw 7.78vw 0 7.78vw;
  border-color: #332638 transparent transparent transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>

<div class="triangle-responsive"></div>
```

Comment: This is the first time I use the `vw` unit, actually. Will learn more about it. Thank you for an answer!